# Multi-Dimensional Array Table Population

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Trying to generate a table via an Array which is fed via a MySQL Query, we pull all the data required in one query and store it in to an array.

The Array Snippett (It currently has over 40 Sub-arrays in it but this is an example)

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [Date] => October-2013
        [TotalPaid] => 100.00
        [OrderStatus] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Date] => October-2013
        [TotalPaid] => 150.00
        [OrderStatus] => 2
    )
```

Our Desired result is to Generate a table which looks like

```
Date           | Processing | Complete | Deleted
October 2013        £150        £100       £0
September 2013      £400        £200       £50
```

And so forth dating back (x) years.

I have managed to get the table to display the correct rows, but we are having issues with the situation of there not being any Complete Transactions for the month so the above desired output ends up like

```
Date           | Processing | Complete | Deleted
October 2013        £150        £100       £0
September 2013      £400        £50
```

The code for this is

```
$MasterSQL = "SELECT DATE_Format(DTStamp, ('%M-%Y')) AS 'Date', SUM(TotalPaid) AS 'TotalPaid', OrderStatus FROM bs_orders GROUP BY OrderStatus, EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM DTStamp) ORDER BY OrderStatus ASC, DTStamp DESC";
        $MasterData= $db->getResults($MasterSQL);

        $Table     = '';
        $Table .= '<h2>Page Title</h2>';
        $Table .= '<p>Some Text</p>';
        $Table .= '<table id="Report">';
            $Table .= '<tr>';
                $Table .= '<th>Pending</th>';
                $Table .= '<th>Complete</th>';
                $Table .= '<th>Problem</th>';
                $Table .= '<th>WP Complete</th>';
                $Table .= '<th>Deleted</th>';
            $Table .= '</tr>';

        $DataArray = array();
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($MasterData)){
            $DataArray[] = $row;
        }

        $DateArr = array();
        foreach($DataArray as $Date){
            if(!in_array($Date['Date'], $DateArr))
            {
                $Table .= '<tr>';
                $Table .= '<td>'.$Date['Date'].'</td>';
                foreach($DataArray as $data){
                    if($data['Date'] == $Date['Date']){
                        $DateArr[] = $Date['Date'];

                        if($data['OrderStatus'] == 1){
                            $Table .= '<td>&pound;'.$data['TotalPaid'].'</td>';
                        }
                        else 
                        if($data['OrderStatus'] == 4){
                            $Table .= '<td>&pound;'.$data['TotalPaid'].'</td>';
                        }
                        else
                        if($data['OrderStatus'] == 3){
                            $Table .= '<td>&pound;'.$data['TotalPaid'].'</td>';
                        }
                        else
                        if($data['OrderStatus'] == 2){
                            $Table .= '<td>&pound;'.$data['TotalPaid'].'</td>';
                        }
                        else
                        if($data['OrderStatus'] == 6){
                            $Table .= '<td>&pound;'.$data['TotalPaid'].'</td>';
                        }

                    } // if($data['Date'] == $Date['Date'])
                } // foreach($DataArray as $data)
                $Table .= '</tr>';
            } // if(!in_array($Date['Date'], $DateArr))
        } // foreach($DataArray as $Date)


        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($DataArray);
        echo '</pre>';

        $Table .= '<tr>';
        $Table .= '<th> </th>';
        $Table .= '<th>Pending</th>';
        $Table .= '<th>Complete</th>';
        $Table .= '<th>Problem</th>';
        $Table .= '<th>WP Complete</th>';
        $Table .= '<th>Deleted</th>';
        $Table .= '</tr>';
        $Table .= '</table>';
        echo $Table;
```

It is probably just a simple fix which I am overlooking, I have attempted numerous methods of if else statements but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: This is a lot of code to digest, but it looks like your issue is within the SQL query itself. Could you post a sqlfiddle with a sample of the data you're trying to work with. I can assure you you'll receive **much** more precise answers if you do, and it will shown that you've done your homework before coming to the stack with a question.

Comment: Is it just me or are all your else..ifs doing the exact same thing? Also, you haven't really told us how a transaction is determined to be complete, deleted, etc. I'm guessing status 1 is complete?

Comment: Please, **DO NOT** use `mysql_query` in new applications. It's deprecated, dangerous if used incorrectly, and is being removed from future versions of PHP. You've got some kind of a wrapper around it here, which is even more terrifying. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) will help you avoid making mistakes like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an array which contains all of the columns you want, in the correct order. Then foreach $dataArray, loop through that columns array and if the value does not exist in the data array, print a blank cell.

Comment: He's using fetch_assoc, there is no 'order'. The array of results he gets will be a key/value pair. If data is not available from a column then it will return empty or null.

Comment: What? I'm saying make an array of the columns he wants in his HTML table. Since some columns are empty/null, he needs to know that he wanted to print a blank HTML cell in that spot. If he doesn't look through a LIST of those columns how can he know that?

Comment: Apologies, I misunderstood. I'm taking this opportunity to ask if it's proper etiquette to delete my previous comment (and ruin the continuity of this conversation we are engaged in) or keep it (and clutter the page with invalid comments)?

Comment: No worries - I have no idea what the rule is on that.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to help you as best I can without an SQLFiddle to work with...

Don't do this:

```
...
foreach($DataArray as $Date){
    if(!in_array($Date['Date'], $DateArr))
...
```

For cycling through those rows, do this instead:

```
...
foreach($DataArray as $rowNum => $row){
...
```

Not only is it much easier to read, but it will greatly simplify your code, which removes the chance of that 'in_array' statement causing an issue (which it could be).

Alternatively, if you wish for your result set to force a '0' on a column rather than a null (which may be causing your problem). Take a look at the IFNULL MySQL function. You might be able to do something like this:

```
IFNULL(Complete , '0')
```

This will change any 'null' results to 0. That could also potentially resolve your issue. Again your answers will be much more relevant with a fiddle to work with; a potential answerer can grab your schema, quickly test it on an AMP stack and find you an answer.